# Given a potential energy function, find expression of the force of a particle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

This comes from an AP review packet.  I'm given a potential energy functon, $$U(r)=br^{-3/2} + c,$$ where $b$ and $c$ are constants, and need to find the expression for the force on the particle.

There's a graph of $U(r)$ given with the problem, but I'm not sure if it's needed or not.  I'm just looking for how to go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$\vec F =-\dfrac{dU}{dr}$$ where r is the radial direction.

From graph you can see the slope of $\brace {U-r}$ graph will give:  $\underbrace{-\vec F}_{\text{ in radial direction.}}$